# Trying to rotate image in direction of mouse pointer on JavaScript canvas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, canvas, rotation

Here is my code:

```
   socket.on('newPositions', function(data) {
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1500, 1000);
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       var img = document.getElementById("player");
       var rotation = -(Math.atan2(data[i].x - event.clientX, data[i].y - event.clientY) * 180 / Math.PI);
       //ctx.drawImage(img, data[i].x, data[i].y, 89, 275);
       ctx.save();
       ctx.translate(data[i].x + 89 / 2, data[i].y + 275 / 2);
       ctx.rotate(rotation);
       ctx.translate(-data[i].x + 89 / 2, -data[i].y + 275 / 2);
       ctx.drawImage(img, data[i].x, data[i].y);
       ctx.restore();
     }
   });
```

Would really appreciate if someone could help me to find a fix, as I have no idea what is wrong at this point :)

Answer (score 0):

Rotation is in radian.
please see:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-transform-rotate-tutorial/